# How to apply a RRule to an external event dragged to the calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

In my react app, I am trying to apply a RRule to an external event dragged into the Calendar.

```
  render() {
  return (<>
    <div className = "draggable-task"
    id = 'my-unique-id'
    key = 'my-unique-id'
    data-event = {
      `{"id": "my-unique-id", "title":"my event", "color": "#ffffff", "backgroundColor": "#000000", "duration": "00:30", "borderColor": "#000000" }`
    }>My event </div>

    <FullCalendar plugins = {[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, bootstrapPlugin, rrulePlugin]}
    initialView = "timeGridWeek"
    headerToolbar = {
      {
        start: 'title',
        center: 'timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth',
        end: 'today prev,next'
      }
    }
    droppable = {true}
    editable = {true}
    eventReceive = {(info) => this.onEventReceive(info)}
    /> 
  </>)
}

componentDidMount() {
  let draggableEl = document.getElementById('my-unique-id');
  if (draggableEl) {
    new Draggable(draggableEl);
  }
}
onEventReceive(info) {
  // set recurring properties
  info.event.rrule = {
    freq: 'daily',
    interval: 1,
    dtstart: info.event.startDate,
    until: info.event.endDate
  };
}
```

The event is correctly added to the calendar when I drag it, but the recurring events do not appear.

Comment: If you want to update the properties of an event after it's been created then you should use the [setProp](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-setProp) function as per the documentation. But...why not just add the rrule to the original `data-event` properties, then it'll be parsed with the rest of the data when the event is first dropped onto the calendar?

Comment: Since it's an external event being dragged onto the calendar, I only know the value of some properties when the event is dragged (like `dtstart`), that's why I can't set the rrule in the original `data-event` object.

Comment: Ok yes of course, that makes sense. So I suggest you try with the setProp method and see if that helps

Comment: I tried it and got the following warning `Could not set prop 'rrule'. Use setExtendedProp instead.`, and when I tried the `setExtendedProp`, it doesn't really work..

Comment: Hm. Maybe because it's part of a plugin. You could potentially raise a ticket about it, I think - see https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs . Although it may be intentional, you never know, but you'll hopefully get an explanation at least, if that's the case.

Comment: Another option / workaround which I think should work is: within the eventReceive callback, instead of attempting to update the generated event, create an entirely new event object combining the data from the created one and the rrule, and then add that to the calendar. Then finally, cancel the adding of the dropped event object using the "revert" callback function (provided in the `info` object).

Comment: Adding a new event and reverting the added one did work! Although not the cleanest way but I think it's the only solution for now, thanks for the help @Adyson.